# SQLAlchemy polymorphic on multiple identities for a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement Single Table Inheritance using SQLAlchemy.
According to the official SQLAlchemy's documentation (here: [official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html)), the way to assign a **single** polymorphic identity, is as follows:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }
```

I want to assign **multiple** identities, for a single class. For example:

```
 class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'))
    company = relationship("Company", back_populates="managers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': ['manager', 'ceo'], 
    }
```

Notice the following line:

```
'polymorphic_identity': ['manager', 'ceo']
```

This line isn't possible (unfortunately).

I would like to know if there's any way of assigning multiple polymorphic identities to a single class.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any example like that in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code won't work because the `polymorphic_identity` of a class is used as a dictionary key. So for the same reason as `[] in {}` raises a `TypeError`, so too does your code.

The usual way to do something like this would be to create a `CEO` class that was a subclass of `Manager` which would then be able to have it's own `polymorphic_identity` as well as `Mapper`. But all that aside, you can create a second `polymorphic_identity` for a given class (but it's kinda hacky).

Each class that inherits from `Base` has reference to the same `polymorphic_map`, which is just a `dict`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
emp_mapper = class_mapper(Employee)
mgr_mapper = class_mapper(Manager)
print(type(emp_mapper.polymorphic_map))  # <class 'dict'>
print(emp_mapper.polymorphic_map is mgr_mapper.polymorphic_map)  # True
```

The `polymorphic_map` maps a `polymorphic_identity` to a `Mapper` so that when a given row is fetched from the database, the value of the column assigned as the `polymorphic_identity` column can be used to get the class that should be used to represent that data. For example, after only defining your `Employee` class, the `polymorphic_map` looks like this: `{'employee': <Mapper at 0x1b1eafcac50; Employee>}`. And after defining the `Manager` class with `'manager'` as the `polymorphic_identity`, it looks like this: `{'employee': <Mapper at 0x25d10b19cf8; Employee>, 'manager': <Mapper at 0x25d0fdbd4e0; Manager>}`

I'll create some test data (I had to remove all references to company table - see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
s = Session()
engineer = Employee(name='engineer')
manager1 = Manager(name='manager1')
manager2 = Manager(name='manager2')
s.add_all([engineer, manager1, manager2])
s.commit()
print(s.query(Employee).all())  # [<__main__.Employee object at 0x000001E5E54A0550>, <__main__.Manager object at 0x000001E5E54A0CF8>, <__main__.Manager object at 0x000001E5E54A0D68>]
print(s.query(Manager).all())  # [<__main__.Manager object at 0x000001E5E54A0CF8>, <__main__.Manager object at 0x000001E5E54A0D68>]
```

Now, lets promote a manager to CEO:

```
manager1.type = 'ceo'
s.commit()
```

This emits a warning:

```
SAWarning: Flushing object <Manager at 0x1e5e54a0cf8> with incompatible polymorphic identity 'ceo'; the object may not refresh and/or load correctly (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
```

But we'll ignore that and try to query the employee table:

```
print(s.query(Employee).all())
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 721, in configure_subclass_mapper
    sub_mapper = mapper.polymorphic_map[discriminator]
KeyError: 'ceo'
```

So the `type` column for manager1 now has a value that isn't present in the `polymorphic_map` and we get a key error. As we are only ever interested in a CEO being represented as a `Manager` then we can just manually put an entry into the `polymorphic_map` associating the key 'ceo' with the `Mapper` for the `Manager` class. E.g:

```
mgr_mapper.polymorphic_map['ceo'] = mgr_mapper
```

Now lets query the employee table again:

```
print(s.query(Employee).all())  #  [<__main__.Employee object at 0x0000020EE7320550>, <__main__.Manager object at 0x0000020EE7320CF8>, <__main__.Manager object at 0x0000020EE7320D68>]
```

Note that it now prints two manager objects again.

Disclaimer: Inside the `Mapper` for `Manager` it maintains a reference to the `polymorphic_identity` of the class (which is `'manager'`), and so our `ceo` key in the `polymorphic_map` points to a mapper that references a `polymorphic_identity` of `manager`. I mention this as while all of this works fine in this example, I do not know whether this might cause bugs elsewhere in sqlalchemy. So, if you use something like this in production, make sure it's well tested.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that using polymorphic identity with a list wasn't possible. Just wonderd what is the best practice in this case. I guess I will write an inherited class for each of my types, using a common super class. I would like to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

I know this has long been answered, but this is another option.

The `polymorphic_on` can also take a `case` according to the docs

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.polymorphic_on

So each class still only has 1 `polymorphic_identity` but in the `polymorphic_on` you can map multiple values to the same identity.

In your case it could look like:

```py
 class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        "polymorphic_on":case(
            [
                (type == "manager", "manager"),
                (type == "ceo", "manager"),
            ],
            else_="employee"
         )
    }


class Manager(Employee):
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'))
    company = relationship("Company", back_populates="managers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'manager', 
    }
```

I have not tried with `in` or SQLAlchemy's `.in_`

Answer (score 1):

**Update** on the [top voted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60265198/19517403)

Starting from SQLAlchmey 2.0, you should no longer add the conditions within a `list` inside the `case` function. Here is the updated solution

```py
 class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        "polymorphic_on":case(
            (type == "manager", "manager"),
            (type == "ceo", "manager"),
            else_="employee"
         )
    }


class Manager(Employee):
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'))
    company = relationship("Company", back_populates="managers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'manager', 
    }
```