# SQLAlchemy Complex Polymorphic Mapping And Deep Table Inheritance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following table structure (I have simplified it as much as possible, narrowed down the child/inheriting tables [there are additional] and removed all irrelevant columns from the provided tables):

```py
## Base is my declarative_base

class AbstractQuestion(Base):
    questionTypeId: Column = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("luQuestionTypes.id"), index=True, nullable=False
    )
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": 0,
        "polymorphic_on": questionTypeId,
    }

class MultiChoiceQuestion(AbstractQuestion):
    id: Column = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractQuestion.id), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": 1}


class AbstractSurveyQuestion(AbstractQuestion):
    id: Column = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractQuestion.id), primary_key=True)
    surveyQuestionTypeId: Column = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("luSurveyQuestionTypes.id"), index=True, nullable=False
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": 2}


class RatingQuestion(AbstractSurveyQuestion):
    id: Column = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractSurveyQuestion.id), primary_key=True
    )
```

The challenge I'm facing is, that I'm trying to make `AbstractSurveyQuestion` have two types of polymorphic mappings - one as a child of `AbstractQuestion` with a `polymorphic_identity` that matches the `questionTypeId`, but I also need it to have a separate `polymorphic_on` mapper for its own child table, which is `RatingQuestion`.
The closest thing I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53155394/5141899), but it doesn't seem to be aiming at exactly what I'm looking for.
I also looked at the [official docs about inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html), but again couldn't find an accurate example to what I'm trying to achieve.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on SQLAlchemy's GitHub repo. Got this answer from the maintainer:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8089#discussioncomment-2878725

I'll paste the contents below as well:

> it sounds like you are looking for mult-level polymorphic_on. We don't support that right now without workarounds, and that's #2555 which is a feature we're unlikely to implement, or if we did it would be a long time from now.
>
> It looks like you are using joined inheritance....so...two ways. The more SQL efficient one is to have an extra "supplemetary" column on your base table that can discriminate for AbstractSurveyQuestion...because if you query for all the AbstractQuestion objects, by default it's just going to query that one table, and needs to know from each row if that row is in fact a RatingQuestion.
>
> the more convoluted way is to use mapper-configured [with_polymorphic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance_loading.html#setting-with-polymorphic-at-mapper-configuration-time) so that all queries for AbstractQuestion include all the tables (or a subset of tables, can be configured, but at minimum you'd need to join out to AbstractSurveyQuestion) using a LEFT OUTER JOIN (or if you really wanted to go crazy it can be a UNION ALL).
>
> the workarounds are a little ugly since it's not very easy to get a "composed" value out of two columns in SQL, but they are contained to the base classes. Below examples work on SQLite and might need tweaking for other databases.
>
> Here's the discriminator on base table demo, a query here looks like:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT aq.id AS aq_id, aq.d1 AS aq_d1, aq.d2 AS aq_d2, CAST(aq.d1 AS VARCHAR) || ? || CAST(coalesce(aq.d2, ?) AS VARCHAR) AS _sa_polymorphic_on 
> FROM aq
> ```
>
> ```py
> from typing import Tuple, Optional
> from sqlalchemy import cast
> from sqlalchemy import Column
> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
> from sqlalchemy import event
> from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
> from sqlalchemy import inspect
> from sqlalchemy import Integer, func
> from sqlalchemy import String
> from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
> from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
>
> Base = declarative_base()
>
>
> class ident_(str):
>
>    """describe a composed identity.
>
>    Using a string for easy conversion to a string SQL composition.
>    """
>
>    _tup: Tuple[int, Optional[int]]
>
>    def __new__(cls, d1, d2=None):
>        self = super().__new__(cls, f"{d1}, {d2 or ''}")
>        self._tup = d1, d2
>        return self
>
>    def _as_tuple(self):
>        return self._tup
>
>
> class AbstractQuestion(Base):
>    __tablename__ = "aq"
>    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>    d1 = Column(
>        Integer, nullable=False
>    )  # this can be your FK to the other table etc.
>    d2 = Column(
>        Integer, nullable=True
>    )  # this is a "supplementary" discrim column
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {
>        "polymorphic_identity": ident_(0),
>        "polymorphic_on": cast(d1, String)
>        + ", "
>        + cast(func.coalesce(d2, ""), String),
>    }
>
>
> @event.listens_for(AbstractQuestion, "init", propagate=True)
> def _setup_poly(target, args, kw):
>    """receive new AbstractQuestion objects when they are constructed and
>    set polymorphic identity"""
>
>    # this is the ident_() object
>    ident = inspect(target).mapper.polymorphic_identity
>
>    d1, d2 = ident._as_tuple()
>    kw["d1"] = d1
>    if d2:
>        kw["d2"] = d2
>
>
> class MultiChoiceQuestion(AbstractQuestion):
>    __tablename__ = "mcq"
>    id: Column = Column(
>        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractQuestion.id), primary_key=True
>    )
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": ident_(1)}
>
>
> class AbstractSurveyQuestion(AbstractQuestion):
>    __tablename__ = "acq"
>
>    id: Column = Column(
>        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractQuestion.id), primary_key=True
>    )
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": ident_(2)}
>
>
> class RatingQuestion(AbstractSurveyQuestion):
>    __tablename__ = "rq"
>
>    id: Column = Column(
>        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractSurveyQuestion.id), primary_key=True
>    )
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": ident_(2, 1)}
>
>
> e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
> Base.metadata.create_all(e)
>
> s = Session(e)
> s.add(MultiChoiceQuestion())
> s.add(RatingQuestion())
> s.commit()
> s.close()
>
> for q in s.query(AbstractQuestion):
>    print(q)
> ```
>
> then there's the one that maintains your schema fully, a query here looks like:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT aq.id AS aq_id, aq.d1 AS aq_d1, CAST(aq.d1 AS VARCHAR) || ? || CAST(coalesce(acq.d2, ?) AS VARCHAR) AS _sa_polymorphic_on, acq.id AS acq_id, acq.d2 AS acq_d2 
> FROM aq LEFT OUTER JOIN acq ON aq.id = acq.id
> ```
>
> ```py
> from typing import Tuple, Optional
> from sqlalchemy import cast
> from sqlalchemy import Column
> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
> from sqlalchemy import event
> from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
> from sqlalchemy import func
> from sqlalchemy import inspect
> from sqlalchemy import Integer
> from sqlalchemy import String
> from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
> from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
>
> Base = declarative_base()
>
>
> class ident_(str):
>
>    """describe a composed identity.
>
>    Using a string for easy conversion to a string SQL composition.
>    """
>
>    _tup: Tuple[int, Optional[int]]
>
>    def __new__(cls, d1, d2=None):
>        self = super().__new__(cls, f"{d1}, {d2 or ''}")
>        self._tup = d1, d2
>        return self
>
>    def _as_tuple(self):
>        return self._tup
>
> class AbstractQuestion(Base):
>    __tablename__ = "aq"
>    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>    d1 = Column(
>        Integer, nullable=False
>    )  # this can be your FK to the other table etc.
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {
>        "polymorphic_identity": ident_(0),
>    }
>
>
> @event.listens_for(AbstractQuestion, "init", propagate=True)
> def _setup_poly(target, args, kw):
>    """receive new AbstractQuestion objects when they are constructed and
>    set polymorphic identity"""
>
>    # this is the ident_() object
>    ident = inspect(target).mapper.polymorphic_identity
>
>    d1, d2 = ident._as_tuple()
>    kw["d1"] = d1
>    if d2:
>        kw["d2"] = d2
>
>
> class MultiChoiceQuestion(AbstractQuestion):
>    __tablename__ = "mcq"
>    id: Column = Column(
>        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractQuestion.id), primary_key=True
>    )
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": ident_(1)}
>
>
> class AbstractSurveyQuestion(AbstractQuestion):
>    __tablename__ = "acq"
>
>    id: Column = Column(
>        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractQuestion.id), primary_key=True
>    )
>    d2 = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {
>        "polymorphic_identity": ident_(2),
>        "polymorphic_load": "inline",   # adds ASQ to all AQ queries
>    }
>
> # after ASQ is set up, set the discriminator on the base class
> # that includes ASQ column
> inspect(AbstractQuestion)._set_polymorphic_on(
>    cast(AbstractQuestion.d1, String)
>    + ", "
>    + cast(func.coalesce(AbstractSurveyQuestion.d2, ""), String)
> )
>
> class RatingQuestion(AbstractSurveyQuestion):
>    __tablename__ = "rq"
>
>    id: Column = Column(
>        Integer, ForeignKey(AbstractSurveyQuestion.id), primary_key=True
>    )
>
>    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": ident_(2, 1)}
>
>
>
> e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
> Base.metadata.create_all(e)
>
> s = Session(e)
> s.add(MultiChoiceQuestion())
> s.add(RatingQuestion())
> s.commit()
> s.close()
>
> for q in s.query(AbstractQuestion):
>    print(q)
> ```